# Html text as tooltip, align to the right

Tags: c++, html, qt, tooltip, text-alignment

I want show such tooltip in Qt:

```
Field1:     some_price1
Field2:     some_price2
Field3:     some_price3
```

and the second column should be aligned to the right, for example

```
Field1:     17.50
Field2:      1.57
Field3:    117.50
```

How can I do it? In the past I use /t and it works perfectly, but now I need html(for coloring) in QToolTip, and only thing I can do is calculate count of spaces, which I need to align prices to the right and put them behind prices.

Comment: Have you tried generating a block of HTML with a `right` aligned attribute and using it as the text of the tooltip? Something like `<p align=right>text</p>`

Comment: I need to kept left side of text as left aligned, and right side of text of the same line as right aligned. I found the solution with <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><tr>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in this way:

```
QString str = QString("<tr><td>Field1:</td><td align=\"right\">%1</td></tr>") + 
              QString("<tr><td>Field2:</td><td align=\"right\">%2</td></tr>");
```

Thanks for replays.